# <lightning:select> peform a function on load

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification) for  I see there are attributes for onchange/onfocus, etc., but nothing similar to onload.

I want to perform a function when the  renders for the first time. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: I am sure this `lightning:select` tag is used inside a component. You can use the `init` handler on the component to fetch values for the select list or do any other operation. [See here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm)

Comment: It worked, thanks @manjit5190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this `lightning:select` tag is used inside a component. You can use the init handler on the component to fetch values for the select list or do any other operation. [See here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm)

Component:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:select options="{!v.options}"></lightning:slelect>
</aura:component>
```

JS

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp) {
        // Make callout and set values of options here

        cmp.set("v.options", <VALUE FROM CALLOUT or somewhere>);
    }
})
```